# Curl POST request for wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, shell, post, curl

Im trying to do a post request in a shell to invoke a wordpress install, but wordpress just tells me "you must provide an e-mail address". Here is what I have:

```
curl -X POST -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" -e "http://dev.example.com/yeshello/wp-admin/install.php?step=2" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate" --data "?step=2&weblog_title=yeshello&user_name=admin&admin_password=admin&admin_password2=admin&admin_email=mathias%40example.com&Submit=Install+WordPress" http://dev.example.com/yeshello/wp-admin/install.php
```

Ive managed to get it to work in a Chrome plugin by the name Postman
here is what I've set up there:

### Headers

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0 Referer: http://dev.feed.no/yeshello/wp-admin/install.php?step=2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

### Raw

*this is raw data, the plugin have a field supporting that*

step=2&weblog_title=yeshello&user_name=admin&admin_password=admin&admin_password2=admin&admin_email=mathias%40feed.no&Submit=Install+WordPress

### URL

*and finally there is a url field*

http://dev.example.com/yeshello/wp-admin/install.php?step=2&weblog_title=yeshello&user_name=admin&admin_password=admin&admin_password2=admin&admin_email=mathias@feed.no&Submit=Install+WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simplified version of original answer. Thank you for your effort, it helped.

`curl --data-urlencode "weblog_title=MY_BLOG_NAME" \
     --data-urlencode "user_name=MYUSERNAME" \
     --data-urlencode "admin_password=MYPASSWORD" \
     --data-urlencode "admin_password2=MYPASSWORD" \
     --data-urlencode "admin_email=MY@EMAIL.COM" \
     --data-urlencode "Submit=Install+WordPress" \
     http://wordpress_host/path_if_any/wp-admin/install.php?step=2`

This is the most simplified I could come up with. I don't see any reason to change user agent string, set referrer url and include all params in POST and GET data. Curl sets correct content header when using `--data` and/or `--data-urlencode`.

The interesting part actually is that `step=2` should be a GET variable and everything else needs to be POST data.

Answer (score 3):

And by the time I wrote the URL heading I tried use the whole url in the curl command, like this:

```
curl -X POST -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" -e "http://dev.example.com/yeshello/wp-admin/install.php?step=2" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate" --data "?step=2&weblog_title=yeshello&user_name=admin&admin_password=admin&admin_password2=admin&admin_email=mathias%40example.com&Submit=Install+WordPress" http://dev.example.com/yeshello/wp-admin/install.php?step=2&weblog_title=yeshello&user_name=admin&admin_password=admin&admin_password2=admin&admin_email=mathias@example.com&Submit=Install+WordPress
```

And it worked :)
But I fugured, why not post this anyways. Hope it helps someone! And if anyone want to clarify why this has to be done, I would love to hear it.